Looking for a martial arts children's movie from I believe the 90's
I'm looking for a movie I saw as a kid, but I can't remember a whole lot from it, but I'll try to list some of what I remember (a few things may be a bit uncertain).

It is in English
There are two main characters. A boy and girl I want to say around 13-15 years old and they both do martial arts.
There are two back stories for the girl that I kind of remember, but I'm not sure which one is the one from the movie. She is either a descendant of an ancient clan and has a certain birthmark/tattoo or she has a artifact from an ancient clan that is a medallion/necklace. Again, not sure which one it is or even if those are correct.
There is a group of bad guys trying to find a way to the ancient clan/get the artifact from the girl so they try to kidnap her.
There is a fights scene at a playground with the boy and girl facing the bad guys.
She eventually does get taken and is being held at what I believe is an amusement park (arcade, rides, etc.).
I remember the boy goes to try and save her and there is a chase scene where he gets in a go-kart with her and the bad guys also get in some and pursue them around the track.

That's about all I remember. I've been looking for a while and decided to give this a shot.
Edits: I'm about 95% sure that the girl is caucasian/white and the boy is asian. I think that the boy is also tasked by either his father or grandfather to protect the girl which is why he goes to save her from the amusement park.

There are parts of this that sound similar to the 2010 remake of The Karate Kid, but I don't remember anything about artifacts, so probably not it--too easy of answer. There is a film from Thailand called Force of Five that's about kids fighting terrorist, but I don't think it's in English. And the ancient artifact part reminds me of The Last Airbender, but that is a not contempary setting. Do you remember the ethenticity of the children??
